# Using sed to get json data from a div tag

Tags: macos, sed, pattern-matching

I'm using curl and I'm getting a big html file back in the response. 
Then I'm piping the response to sed and trying to extract the json part that I'm interested in. 
I'm struggling with getting the sed to cut the lines correctly.

The Html looks simplified like this:

```html
<div>
<div>
<div class="session" data-session='{
"centerId": "175", 
"myid": "2121"
}' data-state="" 
>
<div>
<div>
<div class="session" data-session='{
"centerId": "232", 
"myid": "3333"
}' data-state="" 
>
```

How should I write in sed to only get the json data. 
So the first post would be:

```json
{
"centerId": "175", 
"myid": "2121"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sed` you should rather use proper html and json parsers, e.g. here with xmlstarlet and jq:

```
<infile.html \
xml fo  -o -R 2> /dev/null                |
xml sel -t -m '//div' -v '@data-session'  |
jq .
```

Output:

```json
{
  "centerId": "175",
  "myid": "2121"
}
{
  "centerId": "232",
  "myid": "3333"
}
```